# Regular ClassName with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I've read some answers to similar questions but did not fully understand because of materialUI update where @mui/styles are depricated.

According to mui docs we can create custom styling using *sx* *prop*, smth like this

```
 <Typography variant="h5" sx={{backgroundColor: 'red' }}>Header</Typography>
```

But when I use regular classNames in v5 it works well too:

```
//css

.makeRed {
backgroundColor: red
}
 
// jsx
<Typography variant="h5" className="makeRed">Header</Typography>
```

The question is - does using regular classes has pitfalls and I need to rewrite mui classes?

(have started my mUI jorney yesterday)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been brushing up on Material for a new job and I've found that if you want to make things more easily changeable and run faster you'll work through the framework. The purpose of Material is for enhanced reusability, so you'll want to work with that purpose and align your style in everything you do within the app towards everything being the same.

If anything your best bet is to do:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
makeRed: {
  background-color: 'red'
}

})


export default useStyles;
```

Then in the actual component just have your classes const as.

```
const classes = useStyles();
<Typography className = {classes.makeRed} />
```

UPDATE:

Since this is depricated now, the best way I've found is the following.

```
import styled from '@mui/material';
import Typography from '@mui/material;

const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)(({theme}) => ({
  color: 'blue',
  backgroundColor: 'orange'
}));

export { StyledTypography }
```

Then in your component you import it and use it as a jsx tag.

```
import { StyledTypography } from './styled';

...boiler plate function stuff

return (<StyledTypography> Awesome Sauce </StyledTypography>)
```

Comment: Thank you for describing this reusable logic - that is helpfull for understanding mui usefulness and that is new 'concept' for me. 
Anyway makeStyles is depricated now, but we can create smth similar to what you meant using 'sx' syntax:  
create global object styles: const styles = { makeRed: backgroundColor: 'red' }, import it anywhere and use in mui component: <Box sx={styles.makeRed}/>. 
Thanks for the good idea

Comment: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/26571#issuecomment-881925962

Comment: this seems to be legacy now: https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/